# Oracle move strings to another matching row

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table called `tblrespondent` and my data looks like this:

```
orclid13 | casenm    | commentfld
-------------------------------
27527     2021JV0039  grandmother
27528     2021JV0039  of Liliana/ Possibly Deceased
27529     2021JV0039  Possibly deceased.
27530     2021JV0039  whereabout unknown.
27531     2021JV0039
```

I have several case numbers that have multiple rows like this and I need to move all the comments into the lowest `orclid13`.  The result would look like this with a semicolon in between each comment.

```
orclid13 | casenm    | commentfld
-------------------------------
27527     2021JV0039  grandmother; of Liliana/ Possibly Deceased; Possibly deceased.; whereabout unknown.
27528     2021JV0039  
27529     2021JV0039  
27530     2021JV0039  
27531     2021JV0039
```

How would I approach this?  Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want an update or a result set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you need a `select` query, this could be a way:

```
select orclid13, casenm,
        case
            when row_number()
                    over (partition by casenm order by orclid13) = 1
                then listagg (commentfld, ';')
                        within group (order by orclid13)
                        over (partition by casenm )
        end as commentfld
from tblrespondent
```

Basically, `listagg` aggregates all the comments into a single string, `row_number()` is used to determine whether you are on the first row of the `casenm` set and this result is used by the `case` to show the concatenated string only in the first row of the set.

If you need to `update` your table, you can use the same logic above in a `merge`:

```
merge into tblrespondent t
using (
        select orclid13, casenm, rowid,
                case
                    when row_number()
                            over (partition by casenm order by orclid13) = 1
                        then listagg (commentfld, ';')
                                within group (order by orclid13)
                                over (partition by casenm )
                end as new_commentfld
        from tblrespondent
       ) X
on (x.rowid = t.rowid)
when matched then update set t.commentfld = X.new_commentfld
```

Answer (score 0):

In an `update`, you could do two updates:

```
update tblrespondent r
    set commentfld = (select listagg(r2.commentfld, '; ') within group (order by orclid13)
                      from from tblrespondent r2
                      where r2.casenm = t.casenm
                     )
    where r.orclid13 = (select min(r2.orclid13)
                        from tblrespondent r2
                        where r2.casenm = t.casenm
                       ) ;

update tblrespondent r
    set commentfld = NULL
    where r.orclid13 > (select min(r2.orclid13)
                        from tblrespondent r2
                        where r2.casenm = t.casenm
                       ) ;
```